# Correct hyperlink to the index

Tags: hyperref, indexing

I am writing a document using the book class, and the hyperlink to the index sends the pdf viewer a bit too far, i.e. when I click the top of the screen is at the start of the index instead of displaying the index title. Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}


\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}  % Original name = Contents
\tableofcontents
\index{foo}


\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex


\chapter{foo}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it and click on index, I get to that position :

[image]

How can I have the hyperlink to index send exactly to the index page, with the index title clearly visible at the top ?

Edit: Fixed the order of phantomsection and addcontentsline

Edit 2 : The log with a verbose hyperref is the following :

```
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `Doc-Start' on input line 18.
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `chapter*.1' on input line 20.
(D:\Travail\Bugtex\bug.toc
Package hyperref Info: bookmark on input line 1:
(hyperref)             thecounter {0}
(hyperref)             text {\contentsname }
(hyperref)             reference {chapter*.1}
(hyperref)             toclevel {0}
(hyperref)             type {toc}.
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `chapter*.1' on input line 2.
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `section*.2' on input line 3.
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `chapter.1' on input line 4.
)
\tf@toc=\write4
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.1' on input line 23.
 [1


{C:/Users/Arnaud/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `chapter*.1', line 2.
Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `section*.2', line 3.
Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `chapter.1', line 4.
]
 Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.2' on input line 23.
 [2

]
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `section*.2' on input line 24.
Package hyperref Info: bookmark on input line 25:
(hyperref)             thecounter {0}
(hyperref)             text {\indexname }
(hyperref)             reference {section*.2}
(hyperref)             toclevel {0}
(hyperref)             type {toc}.
 (D:\Travail\Bugtex\bug.ind
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `page.1' on input line 3.
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.3' on input line 5.
 [3

Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `page.1', line 3.

])
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.4' on input line 28.
 [4


]
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `chapter.1' on input line 28.

Chapter 1.
Package hyperref Info: bookmark on input line 28:
(hyperref)             thecounter {1}
(hyperref)             text {\protect \numberline {\thechapter }foo}
(hyperref)             reference {chapter.1}
(hyperref)             toclevel {0}
(hyperref)             type {toc}.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 29.
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.5' on input line 29.
```

Comment: I am using the `\raisebox` command, but it would be only a workaround.

Comment: I am interested in workarounds as well (this is quite urgent), would you just raise the box of the phantomsection, manually finding the right height ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Anchor for the index title that uses `\twocolumn`

In the meanwhile the trouble (order of `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline`) with MWE is fixed and we can look at the real problem:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
```

suffers from a side effect of the optional argument of `\twocolumn`. The title in the optional argument is put at the top of page in one-column mode, but the current contents of the page (anchor setting) is stalled and is added *after* the title in two-column mode.

Therefore the internals of `\begin{theindex}` needs patching to get the anchor at the right place:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{%
  \twocolumn[%
}{%
  \twocolumn[%
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \string\begin{theindex} failed}}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}  % Original name = Contents
\tableofcontents
\index{foo}

\printindex

\chapter{foo}
\end{document}
```

---

### Analysis of old MWE

*Analysis* part is kept, because its method remains useful for debugging similar problems.

With the old MWE of the question I get a link that is *two* pages early.

The following MWE just adds `\listfiles` and option `verbose` to `hyperref` and 
uses one empty line instead of two:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}  % Original name = Contents
\tableofcontents
\index{foo}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\phantomsection
\printindex

\chapter{foo} 
\end{document}
```

Now the `.log` file contains after running two times with `pdflatex`:

```
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `Doc-Start' on input line 6.
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `section*.1' on input line 9.
Package hyperref Info: bookmark on input line 10:
(hyperref)             thecounter {0.0}
(hyperref)             text {Table of Contents}
(hyperref)             reference {section*.1}
(hyperref)             toclevel {1}
(hyperref)             type {toc}.
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `chapter*.2' on input line 12.
 (./test.toc
Package hyperref Info: bookmark on input line 1:
(hyperref)             thecounter {0}
(hyperref)             text {\contentsname }
(hyperref)             reference {chapter*.2}
(hyperref)             toclevel {0}
(hyperref)             type {toc}.
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `chapter*.1' on input line 2.
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `section*.2' on input line 3.
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `chapter.1' on input line 4.
)
\tf@toc=\write5
\openout5 = `test.toc'.

Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.1' on input line 15.
 [1



{/home/one/tl/tldevsrc/Master/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `chapter*.1', line 2.
Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `section*.2', line 3.
Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `chapter.1', line 4.
]
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.2' on input line 15.
 [2

]
Package hyperref Info: bookmark on input line 16:
(hyperref)             thecounter {0}
(hyperref)             text {\indexname }
(hyperref)             reference {chapter*.2}
(hyperref)             toclevel {0}
(hyperref)             type {toc}.
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `section*.3' on input line 17.
 (./test.ind
Package hyperref Info: Reference (link) `page.1' on input line 3.
Package hyperref Info: Anchor `page.3' on input line 5.
 [3

Package `hyperref' Info: End of reference (link) `page.1', line 3.

])
```

**Analysis:**

- Anchor `Doc-Start` is set automatically by `hyperref` at the begin of the document.
- Anchor `section*.1` is caused by the first `\phantomsection` before `\tableofcontents`
- The bookmark for the table of contents is using the anchor before.
- Anchor `chapter*.2` is set by `\chapter*{\contentsname...}`.
  BTW, this anchor can be used instead of `\phantomsection`, see below.
- Links in the table of contents:

  - `section*.1`: first `\phantomsection` before `\tableofcontents`
  - `chapter*.2`: `\tableofcontents`
  - `chapter.1`: `\chapter{foo}`
- Output of page 1 with anchor `page.1`.
- Output of page 2 with anchor `page.2`.
- The bookmark for the index is using `chapter*.2`, the link generated by `\thetableofcontents`.
- Anchor `section*.3` is caused by `\phantomsection` *after* `\addcontentsline` for index.
- Index entry links to `page.1`, the page location of `\index{foo}`.
- Output of page 3 with anchor `page.3`.

**Versions:**

- LaTeX: 2011/06/27
- `book`: 2007/10/19 v1.4h
- `hyperref`: 20112/11/06 v6.83m
- `makeidx`: 2000/03/29 v1.0m

**Summary:**

Both the bookmark and the entry in the table of contents for the index points to the table of contents on page 1 instead to the index on page 3.
This is fixed by the correct order:

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{...}{...}
```

---

### Link for the table of contents

The previous analysis has shown, that the first `\phantomsection` is not needed for the table of contents:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\theindex}{%
  \twocolumn[%
}{%
  \twocolumn[%
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \string\begin{theindex} failed}}

\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

% Put `\addcontentsline` for the table of contents at the
% start of the table of contents to get on its first page
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\contentsname}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\index{foo}

\printindex

\chapter{foo}
\end{document}
```

Because of the indirection (nested `\add(to)contents(line)`), an additional LaTeX run is needed. The trick is that `\addcontentsline` has to go between the title of the table of contents and at the end of its first page.

Comment: I tried both orders, but both give the same result, which is the one in the picture

Comment: @Arnaud: Then post the *correct* minimal example for the problem.

Comment: @Heiko I believe he did it, I am experiencing the same problem after zooming in a page and clicking Index from Table of Contents. I see first index entry as in the OP's picture, not the index name as requested.

Comment: @Christian I believe that's the problem of a page zooming. Your solution is not working for me, it works only when I see a whole page.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek : The MWE is correct, I do not understand the criticism. I just added the precision that the same trouble appears with the reverse order of phantomsection and addcontentsline

Comment: @Malipivo, @Arnaud: Can you compare the analysis with the `.log` file that your system generates? Which versions you are using?

Comment: @Christian Yes, it is highly probable. Hyperlinks themselves work correctly. The problem OP is experiencing is that OP zoomed in TOC page before clicking on the hyperlink.

Comment: @Heiko Yes, my log file looks similar and hyperlinks work correctly. I will post a screenshot before and after clicking the Index.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek and Christian : I have to apologize, the MWE was indeed incorrect - though it is the one I used to generate the picture attached, I do not understand what changed. I am very grateful for this detailed answer explaining my mistake.

Yet, when I put things in the right order, or just input your corrected  MWE, the link still does not lead to the expected location.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The hyperlink does lead to the title page of the index, but not at the correct place in the titlepage : the title is cut out.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, that later patch of yours solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Workaround

I am experiencing the same problem as the OP after zooming in a page and clicking the hyperlinks. I am using the `\chapter*` command to get a wanted effect (raising an anchor).

```
% run: *latex mal-indextext.tex
% plus makeindex, plus another LaTeX run
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
Index foo.\index{foo}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\def\indexname{My index}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\chapter*{\indexname}
\begingroup
\def\clearpage{}
\IfFileExists{\jobname.ind}{\input{\jobname.ind}}{}
\endgroup
\chapter{foo}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:** For clarification, this is the OP's problem, after opening the PDF file, zooming in (600% in the example) the Table of Contents and clicking the **Index** term it gets us to the correct page but uncorrect position (we don't see the Index name). The first picture demonstrates it: left picture is taken before clicking, the right picture is taken after clicking. This is happening to the OP and in solution of Christian Hupfer and i the first solution of Heiko Oberdiek. I have tested that in Adobe Reader and in the TeXworks editor.

**The current situation:**

[image: mwe, wrong solution]

My poor solution solves this problem (picture below, zoom of 300%, the state before clicking is seen on left and situation after clicking the **My index** is seen on right picture), but it is not a recommended solution as I have used the `\chapter*` command to get the Index name and a proper anchor position.

**Edit 2:** Please see the Heiko Oberdiek's update, it solves this problem.

**The requested situation is similar to this one:**

[image: mwe, good solution but poor method]

Comment: Thanks, this does work but it is quite an inconvenient workaround. If no simple solution is posted I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Arnaud I wish I found a better solution.